# iOS Enterprise distribution

Tags: ios, enterprise

Hi looking for a little advice - I need to take an ios app that has been developed on my dev account and approved (by client) using test flight, and upload it to my clients enterprise account? What is the best way to go about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you like explain in depth? by which we can understand it better.

Comment: Change bundle id of your project. Register new app on you client's account , if needed.